# Python Websocket - ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, websocket

i'm actually trying to use websocket hello world example with localhost connection.

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://localhost:5000/websocket", timeout=5)
print ("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print ("Sent")
print ("Receiving...")
result =  ws.recv()
print ("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()
```

And I got the error that:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Are you hosting a server on port 5000 (TCP)?

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer I didn't do anything for the port 5000

Comment: That's the problem. You are opening a client socket to connect on localhost, port TCP 5000. There is no server running on that port. Expected is a server that will answer 5000 and handle HTTPS handshake + HTTPS->WSS upgrade (i.e. a webserver with SSL and websocket support). I think you skipped the other half of the example.

Comment: I'm a littlle bit confused. I guess I missed the server part